I can't bake the light in Unity
I want to bake the light in my game scene in Unity and it shows for 3 days. Where am I going wrong that I can't bake the light? In the past, I would create both shadow and light by rotating the light source around the terrain. I think if I can do that, I probably won't have any difficulty in baking. Where is the error and why can't I bake? I can't wait this long.
In the screenshot it says 7 hours. They said to change the CPU sleep and make it GPU and this time it wrote for more than 3 days. Does anyone know why I can't bake?

Please don't post the same question twice. When nobody answers your question, either have some patience or update the question with more information to make it easier for people to diagnose your problem.
